# Guessing game won't work, also throwing weird syntax errors

Tags: python, syntax, logic

I've spent the better part of an 1.5 hours working on this thing, and I just can't get it to work. Before it started throwing these weird syntax errors, it would continue to say "guess to low, try again". It's not even running in the shell with these errors I've been getting.

Here's the code:

```
import random
gend = random.randint(1,100) #make random number
def compare(gend,guess): #start function

    guessnum = 0 #set guessnumber to zero for later printing

    if gend < guess: #compare gend number against guessed number
        int(raw_input("Too high. Try again. ")) #request another number for user
        guessnum = guessnum + 1 #add 1 to guessnumber, for later printing
    elif gend > guess: #compare gend number against guessed number
        int(raw_input("Too low. Try again. "))#request another number for user
        guessnum = guessnum + 1 #compare gend number against guessed number
    elif gend == guess: #if guessed number=gend, do this
            keepalive = 'much spook' #stop the while loop
            print "Congratulations! You got it in %d guess." % (guessnum)#print da amount of guesses

keepalive = 'rekt' #keepalive substitute

print 'Time to play a guessing game' #no exp needed

guess = int(raw_input("Enter a number between 1 and 100: ") #start off the game

while keepalive == 'rekt': #while loop that does all the work
    compare(gend,guess) #funcion werk

raw_input("Any key to exit") #keep console open so it doesnt autoclose -.-
```

I'd also just like to say thanks to you guys who help, arguably the best learning resource for a good majority of languages.

Comment: When you face errors, don't just tell us it throws an error. Show us the trace back and the exact error message (i.e. copy the output), that makes it much easier to debug.

Comment: Messed up indentation maybe?  Change your text editor to use spaces instead of tabs.

Comment: "these errors"? **which** errors would that be then?

Comment: @delnan Sorry, here it is:

c:\Users\ace\Documents\pythooooon\practiceprobs>guessgame.py
  File "C:\Users\ace\Documents\pythooooon\practiceprobs\guessgame.py", line 23
    while keepalive == 'rekt': #while loop that does all the work
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

You can't see where the carot is pointing in this comments, but it is pointing to the 'e' in while.

Comment: Step #1 fix the syntax errors. Use an editor that supports smart indenting and shows *mismatched parenthesis*.

Comment: Your problem is here: `guess = int(raw_input("Enter a number between 1 and 100: ")` You need to close the int() function with parenthesis.

Comment: If you were to go to the doctor, you wouldn't say "I don't feel good" and expect a diagnosis, would you?  Same thing here... don't just say there is an error... show the error message!  The easier you make it for *volunteers* to help you, the more help you will get.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing parenthesis on the line above the syntax error.

```
guess = int(raw_input("Enter a number between 1 and 100: ") #start off the game
                                                           ^
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error is due to the *previous* line. Python can only tell you where it *noticed* something's off, which is not necessarily where things actually went downhill. One closing paranthesis is missing from `guess = int(raw_input("Enter a number between 1 and 100: ")`.

That it keeps saying "too low, try again" is due to two mistakes:

- You don't assign to `guess` when you ask for another number (you read a number, parse it, then throw it away), so `guess` never changes.
- Inside the function, `keepalive = 'much spook'` doesn't change the same `keepalive` that is used outside of the loop. There several ways to solve this, but which one is appropriate depends on your prior experience and the material you're learning from - consult it to see if anything like this is mentioned.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation about the keepalive being not global. Also, I see that I never assigned the raw_input to guess in the function. Will test it out and post results.

Comment: Ehh, doesn't work. Fixed the parenthesis, was a stupid mistake. I added "global keepalive" in the beginning of my function, that should have fixed that. Still outputting "Too low..." for any number I put in.